# How to check if v-menu is displayed or not

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So, I have a button with a logo displayed. When I hover / click the button, and the menu is opened, the icon should change to a hamburger. The hover part works fine, but what I'm trying to do now is to keep the hamburger icon displayed while the menu is opened.

Does v-menu have an option that checks the state of the menu if it's opened or should I just make my own function that returns a boolean value if my menu is opened or not?

Below is my code :

```
<v-menu bottom offset-y attach="#mainMenuButton">
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <div v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" id="mainMenuButton">
        <main-menu-div>
          <template v-slot:element>
            <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
              <div class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
                <v-icon v-if="hover" size="14" color="white">{{ "$hamburgerMenu" }}</v-icon>
                <v-icon v-else size="16" color="white">{{ "$mainLogo" }}</v-icon>
              </div>
            </v-hover>
          </template>
        </main-menu-div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <v-card class="m-main-menu-panel d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="column" v-for="(column, idx) in mainMenuColumns" :key="'main-menu-column-' + idx">
        <div v-for="(section, index) in column" :key="'section-' + index" class="d-flex flex-column">
          <span class="d-flex align-center mb-2">
            {{ $t(title) }}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-menu>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `v-model` directive on the `v-menu` to check its status.

It is explained with code in the vuetify's doc itself.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#popover-menu